# Where condition on a Count as Column

Tags: sql, sqlite

the Query

```
SELECT strftime('%W', [DatumEintrag], 'weekday 1') Woche, 
       SUM([FOO]), Count(Distinct [DatumEintrag]) as Tage 
FROM MainData
Where [BAR] LIKE 'BC%'
Group By Woche
```

leads to a Table like

```
Woche | FOO | Tage  
41    | 4218| 3  
42    | 5624| 4  
43    | 7030| 5  
44    | 2812| 2
```

How can i get only the data where Tage >= 4.

```
SELECT strftime('%W', [DatumEintrag], 'weekday 1') Woche, SUM([FOO]), Count (Distinct [DatumEintrag]) as Tage 
FROM MainData
Where [BAR] LIKE 'BC%' AND Tage >= 4
Group By Woche
```

Leads to "misuse of aggregate: Count()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite allows you to use column aliases in the `having` clause.  So you can write this as:

```
select strftime('%W', DatumEintrag, 'weekday 1') as Woche, 
       sum([FOO]), 
       count(distinct DatumEintrag) as Tage 
from MainData
where [BAR] like 'BC%' 
group by Woche
having tage > 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use having clause

```
SELECT 
   strftime('%W', [DatumEintrag], 'weekday 1') Woche, 
   SUM([FOO]), 
   Count (Distinct [DatumEintrag]) as Tage 
FROM MainData Where [BAR] LIKE 'BC%' 
Group By Woche
having Count (Distinct [DatumEintrag])>4
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is using nested queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
SELECT strftime('%W', [DatumEintrag], 'weekday 1') Woche, 
       SUM([FOO]), 
       Count (Distinct [DatumEintrag]) as Tage 
FROM MainData 
Where [BAR] LIKE 'BC%' Group By Woche)t
WHERE Tage>=4
```